# Rails command not found in a particular folders

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debian

So, I'm doing a Michael Hartl's RoR tutorial and in the section [2.3.1 A micropost microtour](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/a-demo-app#sec-microposts_resource) command 'rails' have become unknown in my terminal, considering I've been using it just before, in a The Users resource and all throughout the tutorial. And the confusing part is that it's not found only on the levels deeper than the root folder of the projects.

An example:

```
kedakeda@debian:~/RubymineProjects$ ruby -v
ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161) [x86_64-linux]
kedakeda@debian:~/RubymineProjects$ rails -v
Rails 4.0.3
kedakeda@debian:~/RubymineProjects$ cd demo_app
RVM used your Gemfile for selecting Ruby, it is all fine - Heroku does that too,
you can ignore these warnings with 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore /home/kedakeda/RubymineProjects/demo_app/Gemfile'.
To ignore the warning for all files run 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore allGemfiles'.

kedakeda@debian:~/RubymineProjects/demo_app$ rails -v
bash: rails: command not found
```

All relevant inquiries on the SO seem to differ from my problem.
Also, Running Debian 7.4.0 in VirtualBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you're using bundler, execute

```
bundle install
```

To install your gems

```
bundle exec rails -v
```

To use your installed gems/binaries